# django query year of datefield not being extracted

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-queryset

In my django project I have two models Person & Child.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=200)
    family_name = models.ForeignKey(Family, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    gender_is_male = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    birth_place = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=200)
    year_of_birth = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, validators=[MaxValueValidator(datetime.date.today().year), MinValueValidator(1800)])
    month_of_birth = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, validators=[MaxValueValidator(12), MinValueValidator(1)])

    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True) 

class Child(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    father = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='father_of', limit_choices_to={'gender_is_male': True})
    mother = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='mother_of', limit_choices_to={'gender_is_male': False})
```

A Person may have `birth_date` or only `year_of_birth` and/or `month_of_birth`. I need to sort the children from oldest to youngest and I made the following query:

```
children = person.mother_of.all().annotate(
                year_sort=Case(
                    When(
                        person__birth_date__isnull=False, then=('person__birth_date__year')
                    ),
                    default=('person__year_of_birth'),
                    output_field=PositiveIntegerField()
                )
            ).order_by('year_sort')
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError at /members/237/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1956-08-25'
```

When I traceback, I see this:

```
connection:<django.db.backends.sqlite3.base.DatabaseWrapper object at 0x7f0bd3264700>
converter:<function BaseExpression.convert_value.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f0bd1e76d30>
converters:[(3,
  ([<function BaseExpression.convert_value.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f0bd1e76d30>],
   <Case: CASE WHEN <WhereNode: (AND: <django.db.models.lookups.IsNull object at 0x7f0bd1f8d970>)> THEN Col(T3, members.Person.birth_date), ELSE Col(T3, members.Person.year_of_birth)>))]
convs:[<function BaseExpression.convert_value.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f0bd1e76d30>]
expression:<Case: CASE WHEN <WhereNode: (AND: <django.db.models.lookups.IsNull object at 0x7f0bd1f8d970>)> THEN Col(T3, members.Person.birth_date), ELSE Col(T3, members.Person.year_of_birth)>
pos:3
row:[266, 263, 237, '1956-08-25']
rows:<itertools.chain object at 0x7f0bd1e8f580>
self:<django.db.models.sql.compiler.SQLCompiler object at 0x7f0bd1e8f3d0>
value:'1956-08-25'
```

It seems that the expression `then=('person__birth_date__year')` is being converted into `THEN Col(T3, members.Person.birth_date)` instead of `THEN Col(T3, members.Person.birth_date.year)`

Am I assuming correctly? What is the error in my code?

Comment: Can you try this code with other databases like Postgresql?

Comment: Don't have Postgresql. Is it an Sqlite issue?

Comment: It is possible, if you can try with other databases, it would great.

Comment: Till I can check the issue with other databases, a workaround used by inserting a `child_order` in the model and manually updating this field